# Use topoJSON in Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, topojson

I'm learning how to use Leaflet to make online interactive maps for public health purposes (experienced ArcGIS user, Mapbox TileMill). I'm taking it slow so I understand each piece of code, and I'm working from the Leaflet choropleth [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) as I want to make choropleth maps. The current task I'm stuck on is how to correctly add topoJSON data to a Leaflet map. I've tried the following code to convert the us states geoJSON to topoJSON, but it hasn't worked. Any suggestions?

```
    var geojson;

    var test = topojson.feature(us-states-topo, us-states-topo.objects.layer1 );

    geojson = L.geoJson(test, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
```

I've reviewed the topoJSON API [reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference), but I'm sure I must be making a simple error as I am a beginner to JavaScript in general. Thank you all for your help!

Best
Eli

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using your [browser debug tools](http://debugbrowser.com) to start through debugging this.

```
var test = topojson.feature(us-states-topo, us-states-topo.objects.layer1 );
```

This is not valid JavaScript: `us-states-topo` is not a valid variable name, since `-`s are not permitted.